# Linear systems of equations with 4 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I tried to solve these systems of equations in my book:
\begin{align}
7&x+4y+3z+2w=46\\
5&x-y+4w=23\\
&x+z=6\\
3&x+7w=15
\end{align}

I tried to solve it in many different ways, but I still haven't gotten $x=5$, $y=2$, $z=1$ and $w=0$ which are the solutions of these systems of equations.

Did I make a mistake? How did the book get $x=5$, $y=2$, $z=1$ and $w=0$?

Comment: Linear systems of equations are very tedious when you have to do them by hand. Just check you work. Again. Again. And you need a very steady hand too.

Comment: Or maybe my book is wrong.

Comment: No it's not. The given values satisfy the equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $z = 6 - x$ we can eliminate $z$ so we get:

$$7x+4y+3(6-x)+2w=46$$

Then distributing the $3$:
$$7x+4y+18-3x+2w=46$$

Moving variable terms to left of the left side and constant term to right of left side then combining like terms we get:
$$4x+4y+2w+18=46$$

Subtracting $18$ from both sides so we get
$$4x+4y+2w=28$$

Dividing by $2$, then it becomes:
$$2x+2y+w=28$$
$$5x-y+4w=23$$
$$3x+7w=15$$

Then deriving from the first equation we get

$$w=14-2x-2y$$

Substituting $w$ we get:

$$5x-y+4(14-2x-2y)=23$$
$$3x+7(14-2x-2y)=15$$

By the process the steps for the first one are below:

$$5x-y+56-8x-8y=23$$
$$5x-y-8x-8y+56=23$$
$$-3x-9y+56=23$$
$$-3x-9y=-33$$

Let's get rid of the negatives:

$$3x+9y=33$$

And the steps for the second one are below:

$$3x+98-14x-14y=15$$
$$-11x-14y+98=15$$
$$-11x-14y=-83$$

Get rid of the negatives, there are the 2 equations:

$$3x+9y=33$$
$$11x+14y=83$$

We could do elimination here:

$$11(3x+9y)=11\times 33$$
$$3(11x+14y)=3\times 83$$

We get then:

$$33x+99y=363$$
$$33x+42y=249$$

Subtracting one from the other we get:

$$(33x+99y)-(33x+42y)=363-249$$

We can distribute the minus sign on the left side:

$$33x+99y-33x-42y=363-249$$

Simplifying we get:

$$57y=114$$

Dividing both sides by $57$ we get:

$$y=2$$

Now let's plug this in into any one of the equations before multiplying (in this case, I used $3x+9y=33$ just for simplicity, simplifying, through the steps:

$$3x+9\times 2=33$$
$$3x+18=33$$
$$3x=15$$
$$x=5$$

We've got $x=5$ and $y=2$. Can you finish the rest to get $z=1$ and $w=0$?

Comment: That's the longest answer I've ever saw!

Comment: Only because the equation you gave is a equation with 4 unknowns.

Comment: Yep got it and got exactly what the book told

Answer (score 0):

With $z=6-x$ we can eliminate the variable $z$ so
we get
$$2x+2y+w=14$$
$$5x-y+4w=23$$
$$3x+7w=15$$
Using
$$w=14-2x-2y$$
we get
$$x+3y=11$$
$$11x+14y=83$$

with
$$x=11-3y$$ we get
$$-11(11-3y)-14y=-83$$
so
$$y=2$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, and then I get exactly x=5, y=2, z=1 and w=0.

Comment: That is nice, so your problem is solved now?

Comment: Yes. I thought so that I made a mistake

Comment: Sorry, I had the more longer answer